# Setting up a JSF project without maven

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I used to build my projects with maven. Now I want to do it 'manually'. But I struggle a little bit with directory order and other stuff. I first just created a new dynamic web project in eclipse and added JSF libraries. Now I tried to deploy a hello world page onto a tomcat 7. But jsf-tags are not getting rendered.

Here is my directory structure:

[image]

Anybody has an idea where the mistake is? Am I missing a library or is my structure wrong?

cheers

---

It finally works! thank's to balusc

Comment: please post your `web.xml` and `.xhtml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But jsf-tags are not getting rendered.

This means that the `FacesServlet` isn't mapped in `web.xml` or you didn't make the URL in browser address bar to match the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet`. The `FacesServlet` is the one responsible for parsing JSF tags and doing all the JSF works.

Assuming that the `url-pattern` of the `FacesServlet` as definied in `web.xml` is `*.jsf`, then you need to open the `start.xhtml` by http://localhost:8080/fitnessverwaltung/start.jsf instead of http://localhost:8080/fitnessverwaltung/start.xhtml.

You can also change the `url-pattern` to `*.xhtml`, then you don't need to worry about this.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I've same configuration as you suggested! Though I can not run "Hello World" application.